# How to commit just part of transaction PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I need ideas to solve the problem where there's an order to be updated, and  payments to be created to this order. But if the order charging fails. The updates made to the order should be undone, but the charges created to it should persist.

Example controller code:

```
$order = Order::find(1);

DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        $order->update(['status' => 1]);
        chargeOrder ($order);

    } catch (PaymentErrorException $e) {

        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;

    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) {

        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;

    }


DB::commit();
```

Example function that make the order charging:

```
function chargeOrder( $order ) {

    $payments_service->charge($order);
    $order->payments()->create( new Payment() );

}
```

What i need is, when a PaymentErrorException occurs, only the $order->update() should be undone, but the changes made inside chargeOrder function, should persist.

Comment: You are referring to a "createOrder" function which is not present. Do you mean "chargeOrder"?. Generally speaking you have the chance to "fix" things in the catch-area. That is the place to undo the update. But you have the problem that you don't know where the Exception happened. If it happened before "chargeOrder" the changes don't persist because they never happen.

Comment: 1 - Yes, it's chargeOrder.
2 - It's just a code example, to explain the problem in a nutshell. In the example the PaymentErrorException will occur inside chargeOrder() if something wrong happened during the charging process.

Comment: Could not you just use a new connection to make chargeOrder?

Comment: @madz I think that's an alternative, need to try it. But if i could handle this without making a new connection, would be better.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to run chargeOrder, commit those changes, and then run the update, and commit them separately? If the charges must always be applied no matter what, then better to treat them as two individual transactions, I would think

Comment: @Adyson that male sense, but the chargeOrder function depends of the previous modifications made out of it.

Comment: Then in the case where the update fails, how can you possibly expect to still apply the charges, since you won't have the updated order details available in order to do so? I'm not following the logic of that

Comment: Well, when the chargeOrder function runs, the order status is 1, even though it's not persisted yet. And a payment tuple is created. Then if the payment fails for some reason, the change tô the status of the order must  be undone but the payment tuple should stay there. Does it make sense ?

Comment: The payment tuple will be there as a register of an attempt of charging.

Comment: Ok that's a bit clearer. But where should the "payment tuple" be recorded? Is it against the Order record, or somewhere else? Which part of the chargeOrder process creates it? Is the value held in a variable you can access in PHP, or only in a database table? We still need a bit more info to figure out exactly what is going on. It might make sense to revise your question with a fuller description of the situation. The exact solution may depend on these details.

Comment: Inside chargeOrder, the second line creates the payment tuple. And for the problem i'm having, it doesn't really matter how the real code works, since it's a transaction managing problem.

Comment: Can you answer my other questions as well please? I didn't ask them for no reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
$order = Order::find(1);
$previousStatus = $order->status;

DB::beginTransaction();

    try {

        $order->update(['status' => 1]);
        chargeOrder ($order);

    } catch (PaymentErrorException $e) {

        $order->update(['status' => $previousStatus]);

    } 
    catch (\Exception $e) {

        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;

    }

DB::commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, thar works, but that is just what i'm to  avoid. The real code updates many models, and rollbacking them manually, would be a bad soluction :(